# magnets pancake copper coil

Tags: coil, power-generation

I am winding 6 gage copper wire into a flat pancake-shaped coil.

If magnets are placed under the coil, across the diameter of the coil, and all of the magnets point their north poles upwards, will this generate electricity?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it 6 gauge? That is giant, normally one would attempt to use a smaller size (insulated wire, otherwise all you have a large block of copper...) so that you can achieve many turns. One can then generate electricity by providing a moving magnetic field around the wire. The change in magnetic field is what induces the electrons to move through the coil.

Comment: what's with the Tesla coil tag???

Answer (score 6):

Not if they're not moving. What induces a current in a coil of wire is a *changing* magnetic field, so a static one won't do anything.